# Bash command line parsing maintaining quotes of options

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Without introducing `getopts`, I'd like to parse expressions like so:

`./cli.sh data i -f -f="./path/to/file.txt" --flags="--a --b"`

And variations/combinations thereof:

`./cli.sh -file="./path/to/file.txt" data --flags="--a --b" -f i`

Unfortunately, I am stuck with reading all optional values of the long options submitted, for example: `--flags="--a --b"` only returns `--a` as value for the long option `--flags`.

I have created a minimalized version of a parser which exhibits my current issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

__init_system () {
    CMD_SED="sed"
    CMD_SED_EXT="sed -E"
}

__init_system_Darwin () {
    __init_system
    CMD_SED="gsed"
    CMD_SED_EXT="gsed -E"
}

invoke_func () {
    SYSTEM=$(uname)
    FUNC=$1 && shift 1
    declare -f ${FUNC}_${SYSTEM} >/dev/null
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && { ${FUNC}_${SYSTEM} "$@"; return $?; } || { ${FUNC} "$@"; return $?; }
}

handle_cli_harmonizing () {
    cli_adjusted=$(echo "$@" | ${CMD_SED_EXT} \
                    -e 's@([ ])+@ @g'\
                    -e 's@\<h\>@help@g'\
                    -e 's@\<e\>@enable@g'\
                    -e 's@\<d\>@disable@g'\
                    -e 's@\<i\>@import@g'\
                    -e 's@\<sl\>@showlog@g'\
                    -e 's@\<st\>@status@g'\
                    | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | xargs
                )
    #echo ">>>  Original: <$@>"
    #echo ">>>  Adjusted: <$cli_adjusted>"
}

handle_cli_parsing () {
    for param in $@; do
        case ${param} in
            start|stop|status|enable|disable|data|showlog)
                CMD=$param
                ;;
            help|app|stats|import|export|dbinfo|exec)
                SPEC=$param
                ;;
            --*|-*)
                #echo ">>> Found param: <$param>"
                OPT="$OPT $param"
                ;;
            *)
                echo ">>> Parsing mismatch: $param"
                ;;
        esac
    done
}

handle_cli_optparams () {
    for opt in $OPT; do
        case "$opt" in
            --force|-f)
                OPT_FORCE=1
                ;;
            --file=*|-f=*)
                OPT_FILE=1
                FILE=${opt#*=}
                ;;
            --flags=*)
                OPT_FLAGS=1
                FLAGS=${opt#*=}
                ;;
            *)
                echo ">>> Unknown/unimplemented option specifier: $opt"
                ;;
        esac
    done
}

invoke_func __init_system
invoke_func handle_cli_harmonizing "$@"
invoke_func handle_cli_parsing ${cli_adjusted}
invoke_func handle_cli_optparams

echo "DEBUG[   CLI]: CMD=$CMD SPEC=$SPEC"
echo "DEBUG[TOGGLE]: FORCE=$OPT_FORCE FILE=$OPT_FILE FLAGS=$OPT_FLAGS"
echo "DEBUG[  OPTS]: FILE=$FILE FLAGS=$FLAGS"
```

Expected ouput:

```
$ ./cli.sh data i -f -f="./path/to/file.txt" --flags="--a --b"
DEBUG[   CLI]: CMD=data SPEC=import
DEBUG[TOGGLE]: FORCE=1 FILE=1 FLAGS=1
DEBUG[  OPTS]: FILE=./path/to/file.txt FLAGS=--a --b
```

Current output:

```
$ ./cli.sh data i -f -f="./path/to/file.txt" --flags="--a --b"
>>> Unknown/unimplemented option specifier: --b
DEBUG[   CLI]: CMD=data SPEC=import
DEBUG[TOGGLE]: FORCE=1 FILE=1 FLAGS=1
DEBUG[  OPTS]: FILE=./path/to/file.txt FLAGS=--a
```

<strike>It's probably some quoting issue or a missing `set`, however I seem to be stuck here, and I'd really prefer to keep the simplistic approach I have taken.</strike>

I'd be especially stocked if someone would additionally offer a shell-only (no bashims) version for portability concerns, but that's icing on the cake. Mind you, this is only a very simple part of the whole parser I have written; enough to exhibit my current challenge.

I have read all the suggested linked issues while writing this question, and I have pondered for a while on [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash).

---

> **Update (2020/09/12):** Even though this question has prematurely been downvoted, I found an elegant and more flexible solution, and have posted it as an answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60890883/619961). It still beats getopt or any other approach I have seen concerning my specific requirements to command line parsing.

Comment: This is a FAQ. TL;DR don't do that. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is here:

```
OPT="$OPT $param"
```

This is where the spaces embedded in `$param` become indistinguishable from the space used to append to the end of `$OPT`.

You can avoid this problem by making `OPT` an array, append values to it correctly:

```
OPT+=("$param")
```

... and then use array syntax to iterate over the values of the array:

```
for opt in "${OPT[@]}"; do
```

... and so on, consistently, everywhere, and watch out for correct double-quoting.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to actually tackle the question. I have posted the solution which I was after below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60890883/619961. I still accepted yours for at least trying to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Even after years of abandonment, I'd like to describe the solution to the question asked above.

While [janos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47638121/619961) gave me the pointer, the solution is actually much simpler and maintains the original flexibility envisioned:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

handle_cli_parsing () {
    while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
        param=$1
        [ x"$param" = x"sl" ] && param=showlog
        [ x"$param" = x"sh" ] && param=showlog
        [ x"$param" = x"h" ]  && param=help
        [ x"$param" = x"i" ]  && param=import
        [ x"$param" = x"e" ]  && param=enable
        [ x"$param" = x"d" ]  && param=disable
        case ${param} in
            start|stop|status|enable|disable|data|showlog)
                CMD=$param
                ;;
            help|app|stats|import|export|dbinfo|exec)
                SPEC=$param
                ;;
            --force|-f)
                OPT_FORCE=1
                ;;
            --file=*|-f=*)
                OPT_FILE=1
                FILE=${param#*=}
                ;;
            --flags=*)
                OPT_FLAGS=1
                FLAGS=${param#*=}
                ;;
            --*|-*)
                echo ">>> New param: <$param>"
                ;;
            *)
                echo ">>> Parsing mismatch: $param"
                ;;
        esac
        shift 1
    done
}

handle_cli_parsing "$@"

echo "DEBUG[   CLI]: CMD=$CMD SPEC=$SPEC"
echo "DEBUG[TOGGLE]: FORCE=$OPT_FORCE FILE=$OPT_FILE FLAGS=$OPT_FLAGS"
echo "DEBUG[  OPTS]: FILE=$FILE FLAGS=$FLAGS"
```

The output is now as expected and the parsing as flexible as intended:

```
$ ./cli.sh data i -f -f="./path/to/file.txt" --flags="--a --b"
DEBUG[   CLI]: CMD=data SPEC=import
DEBUG[TOGGLE]: FORCE=1 FILE=1 FLAGS=1
DEBUG[  OPTS]: FILE=./path/to/file.txt FLAGS=--a --b
```